# Cancelling Earth's Magnetic Field. How effective is Helmholtz's coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, geomagnetism

If there is a pipe of very small radius with electrons moving inside it, and I need to cancel the Earth's Magnetic Field as otherwise it would affect the motion of the electrons (right?). 
How effective will be Helmholtz's coil for this purpose?

Comment: "how effective is X at Y" is the same type of unanswerable question as "how long is a piece of string".

Comment: NASA's Goddard Space Flight Center has its own Helmholtz facility, which is a big Helmholtz coil used to test the magnetic fields generated by a spacecraft.  The purpose is to generate a model which can be subtracted from measurements when by a magnetometer when in space.  The facility has dozens of magnetometers scattered around the main coil to measure the background field one needs to subtract in order to isolate the spacecraft fields.  It works quite well...

Answer (score 0):

A helmholtz's coil produces a somewhat uniform magnetic field aligned with its axis of symmetry at the center of the coil arrangement.  Decades ago I used a computer program doing numeric integration to calculate the field at various points within the central region, but I no longer have the program or the results.  (The field at the mid-point is not difficult to calculate.) In an e/m apparatus, the coil is about a meter in diameter and the field is fairly uniform within a beam tube with a diameter of about 30 centimeters.
You would need to align your coils with the earth's field and then use some kind of sensor to adjust the current and explore the field.

Comment: @R. W. Bird. thanks for the answer. my case is that, the diameter of the channel is very small. it is like a wire. And you did not say how effective the helmholtz's coil would be. Can you remember the conclusion of your program from the decades ago?

Comment: Somewhere I found that at the axis, the value of B= [(4/5)^1.5 * mu_0 * n* I] /R. Can I assume that it is in the small region of the entire diameter of the wire with very small diameter of let's say 1 mm?

Comment: The small diameter of your channel is not a problem as long as is lined up with the axis of the coils.  As the length moves away from the mid-point it may see a change in the field.  As long as you stay near the axis, the field can be calculated as the sum of contributions from each of the two coils.